# IIS won't serve Net 6, even though the Hosting Bundle is installed

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-6.0

When I go to my app pool to select the net CLR Version, 6 isn't there. Only 4. I've installed and reinstalled the Net 6 Hosting Bundle. Restarted my machine. DotNet --info from a command prompt shows 6.0.5 runtimes. But no love from IIS.
I'm running on a fresh build of Windows Server 2022. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

According to document, we suggest you could set the .NET CLR Version to No Managed Code because the Core Common Language Runtime (CoreCLR) for .NET Core is booted to host the app in the worker process, not the desktop CLR (.NET CLR).

So if you want to host asp.net core application in IIS, don't forget to install the core runtime and then it will work well.

Comment: This is the answer. Not intuitive when poking around inside of IIS Manager, but this worked.

Comment: Here are some screenshots of how to do this for better clarity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1084449/how-do-i-get-net-6-into-the-application-pool-on-wi

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it turns out iis, is, in fact, serving my net 6 website, even though its app pool isn't targeting net 6. I just tried running and it worked. I guess this is one of those changes that has come about with net core, and there's some documentation I didn't read carefully enough. Sorry for any inconvenience.